# Columns in LibreOffice Writer always spread all the way to the end of the document

Tags: libreoffice

I need to create a docx document that has a small portion in the middle of the document split into two columns, but whenever I save the document, close it and then open it again, it turns out those two columns have stretched all the way to the bottom and engulfed all the remaining text, like here:

[image: here]

How to prevent that from happening?

Comment: Have you looked at this tutorial for columns? http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2015/04/libreoffice-writer-for-beginner-columns.html

Comment: It only covers the very basics, it won't help here.

Comment: What version of LO are you using, and how exactly are you creating the columns?

Comment: It's 5.1.6.2, I select the text, then go to Formatting->Columns and choose 2 and specify the custom width of the columns and the spacing.